# How can I upload videos to YouTube using selenium chrome driver?

Tags: python, selenium, youtube, selenium-chromedriver

I do not want to use the YouTube API at all as I find it very limiting. Is there a way I could upload my videos to YouTube in Python by using Selenium? The problem that I am running into is that Google isn't letting me sign in. is there any way I could upload videos to YouTube without the use of the YouTube API?

This is my code:

```
blist = []
b1 = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
email = "email@gmail.com"

blist.append(b1)

for browser in blist:
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)
    browser.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin")

    loginBox = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]') 
    loginBox.send_keys(email)

    nextButton = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierNext"]') 
    nextButton[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change your user agent to be able to sign in to Google, Try this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

path = path

useragent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.18"
options_ = Options()
options_.add_argument('user-agent='+useragent)

driver =  webdriver.Firefox(options=opts ,executable_path=PATH)

driver.get('https://youtube.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

give it a shot ytb_up based selenium

https://github.com/wanghaisheng/ytb-up
features YOU MAY NEED

1. proxy support

auto detect whether need a proxy
2. cookie support

for those multiple channels under same google account
3. schedule time publish

you can explictly specify a date and time for each video or you can set publish policy and daily public count,for example,daily count is 4,you got 5 videos,then first 4 will be published 1 day after the upload date ,the other 1 will be 2 days after the upload date
4. fix google account verify